# Integer parameter gets default value when passing string in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got a controller action like this:

```
[HttpGet("test/{value}")]
public object Get(int value)
{
    return new {value};
}
```

When I make a request to `http://localhost:53615/test/asdf` I was expecting the action to not be invoked and instead get a 404 response. But instead it is invoked with 0 as value.

Is there any way to get the behaviour I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constraint on the param will cause a 404 to be returned if no match can be found:

`[HttpGet("test/{value:int")]`